# How to access nested arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I am subscribing to my data from an http get method:

```
  getEds(): void {
    this.edService.getEds()
      .subscribe((eds: Education) => {
        this.eds = eds.educationData;
        console.log(this.eds:codeschool);
      });
  }
```

I am trying to display my courses for codeschool in an *ngFor loop but do not know how to access the data. My console log will show the entire array of objects so I know I am receiving the correct info. I've tried various syntax:

```
.subscribe((eds: any) => {
            this.eds = eds.educationData.course;

.subscribe((eds: any) => {
            this.eds = eds.educationData['codeschool'];

.subscribe((eds: any) => {
            this.eds = eds.educationData.codeschool;
```

None of these syntax work and the log shows undefined. I found this page which has great info and what I tried to use as a baseline.

[Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

However, I do not know what is wrong or why I cannot get the data I need. When I use

```
  .subscribe((eds: any) => {
    this.eds = eds.educationData;
```

and I log out (this.eds), my log shows:

```
[{…}] 
0:{codeschool: Array(14), egghead: Array(6)}
 length:1
 __proto__:Array(0)
```

Beyond this I haven't been able to get the data I want...... :(

Comment: It seems this getEds() returns an array; so, as explained by @Sidhanshu_, you can access each item by its index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Please use tags carefully. Your question has nothing to do with angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
eds.educationData[0].codeschool
```